# XML - Open quote is expected for attribute

Tags: xml

I am trying to add a dtd for the following xml but i get `Open quote is expected for attribute "play" associated with an element type "movie"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE table [
<!ATTLIST movie play (yes | No ) >
]>
<table>
    <movie play="yes">
    </movie>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is required, as in:

```
<!ATTLIST movie play (Yes|No) "Yes">
```

The error message could be better :-)

Comment: Thanks `xmlvalidation.com` was driving me nuts